# ORDER BY SUM VALUE without groupby - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Hello all,

```
   $sql = " SELECT prd.id as id,prd.weight as wgh,
           prd.srpid as srno,prd.dollarval as dolval,catid.id
           FROM productname as prd
           INNER JOIN catid as caid ON prd.catid = caid.id
           Where 1=1
           ORDER BY sid ASC "
  $sqlquery = mysql_query($sql);
```

where id is primary , auto-increment

Above has below value :

```
id | wgh | srno| dolval 
1    1.05   1     155
2    1.00   3     300
3    0.67   2     170
4    0.01   3     140
5    0.20   2     50
6    0.35   1     300
7    2.04   4     190
8    3.0    5     200
```

After doing PHP logic i get below result as output ( display ) :

```
echo"<table  width=\"100%\" border=\"1\">
         <tr>
            <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\"><strong>Sr.No</strong></td>
            <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\"><strong>Cur Wg</strong></td>
            <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\"><strong>Dollar</strong></td>
         </tr>";

 $srno = 1;
 $pid = null;
 $sumnew = 0;
 $sumdollor = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery)){

       $rowval =  $row['srno'];  // **** result is on this value.....

        if ($rowval == $pid || $pid === null){

           echo "<tr>";

           if($pid != $rowpkts){
              echo'<td align="center" valign="top">'.$srno++.'</td>';
           }else{
              echo'<td align="center" valign="top"></td>';
           }

           echo'<td align="center"  valign="top">'.number_format($row["wgh"],2,'.','').'</td>';
           echo'<td align="center" valign="top">'.round($row["dolval"],0).'</td>';

          echo "</tr>";  

          $pid = $rowval;        
          $sumnew += number_format($row["wgh"],2,'.','');
          $sumdollor+= round($row["dolval"],0);

      }else{

       echo "<tr>
         <td></td> 
         <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\"><strong>".number_format($sumnew,2,'.','')."</strong></td>
         <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\"><strong>".$sumdollor."</strong></td>
       echo "</tr>";

      <tr><td colspan='3' height='18px'></td></tr>";


          echo "<tr>";

           if($pid != $rowpkts){
              echo'<td align="center" valign="top">'.$srno++.'</td>';
           }else{
              echo'<td align="center" valign="top"></td>';
           }

           echo'<td align="center"  valign="top">'.number_format($row["wgh"],2,'.','').'</td>';
           echo'<td align="center" valign="top">'.round($row["dolval"],0).'</td>';

          echo "</tr>";  

          $sumnew = number_format($row["wgh"],2,'.','');
          $sumdollor = round($row["dolval"],0);
          $pid = $rowval;

      }
}

       echo "<tr>
         <td></td> 
         <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\"><strong>".number_format($sumnew,2,'.','')."</strong></td>
         <td align=\"center\" valign=\"top\"><strong>".$sumdollor."</strong></td>
       echo "</tr>";

 echo"</table>";
```

**From Above  PHP code  *i get below result*  :**

```
Sr.No   Wgh     Dollar
 1      1.05      155
        0.35      300
-----------------------
                  455  //( 155+300=455)
------------------------
2       0.67      170
        0.20       50
------------------------
                  220
------------------------
3       1.00      300
        0.01      140
------------------------
                  440
------------------------
4       2.04      190
------------------------
                  190
------------------------
5       3.00      200
------------------------
                  200
```

But i NEED TO display above result in *Sum of dollar higher in first*, that higher dollar (that's 445,440,220...etc) of sum should come first and then so on...**that's NEED AS below**

```
Sr.No   Wgh     Dollar
 1      1.05      155
        0.35      300
-----------------------
                  455  //( 155+300=455)
-----------------------
2       1.00      300
        0.01      140
-----------------------
                  440
-----------------------
3       0.67      170
        0.20       50
------------------------
                  220
------------------------
4       3.00      200
------------------------
                  200
------------------------
5       2.04      190
------------------------
                  190
```

how i can get above result please help me... if there is any other way let me know will try to change above format too but need result ...

Edited : if some one have solution with **groupby** ..that would also help me ..but i have not used **group by** as i need to display all 8 value...
Thanks

Comment: Why would you not want to use the `GROUP BY` function?
Just FYI your tabs (spaces) seem to be a little bit off

Comment: Sir, i did groupby but need to display all 8 row value ..if i do group-by then it only show 4 row value ... hence thats the reason...

Comment: A possible solution would be to create a List of the items before you display them. This would offer you the possibility to add the `sum` of `Dollar` and you could display after sorting this list

Comment: You have a table called catid? You don't find that confusing?

Comment: @strawbeery that table is used ..but i haven't shown all my query ...to avoid confusion ....

Comment: @mathieu , can u please show me ..as my mind is not working now ...i have tried to build some logic ..but fail...hence have ask for solution here ...it would be great if you or  some one can help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this SQL, which produces an output (and order) that is close to what you want to generate:

```sql
SELECT     prd.srpid as srno, 
           prd.weight as wgh,
           prd.dollarval as dolval,
           s.dollarsum
FROM       productname as prd
INNER JOIN catid as caid ON prd.catid = caid.id
INNER JOIN (select   srpid,
                     sum(dollarval) dollarsum
           from      productname
           group by  srpid) s ON s.srpid = prd.srpid
ORDER BY   s.dollarsum DESC,
           prd.srpid DESC,
           prd.weight DESC
```

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7196c/2).

The output generated is:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| srpid | weight | dollarval | dollarsum |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     |  1.05  |  155      | 455       |
| 1     |  0.35  |  300      | 455       |
| 3     |  1     |  300      | 440       |
| 3     |  0.01  |  140      | 440       |
| 2     |  0.67  |  170      | 220       |
| 2     |  0.2   |  50       | 220       |
| 5     |  3     |  200      | 200       |
| 4     |  2.04  |  190      | 190       |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

So in PHP you would need to take the value returned in the last column and  output it as a separate "sub-total" row whenever you get at a new section.

I would not go that far, but you could even let the SQL produce those subtotals as rows:

```sql
SELECT     prd.srpid as srno, 
           prd.weight as wgh,
           prd.dollarval as dolval,
           s.dollarsum
FROM       productname as prd
INNER JOIN catid as caid ON prd.catid = caid.id
INNER JOIN (select   srpid,
                     sum(dollarval) dollarsum
           from      productname
           group by  srpid) s ON s.srpid = prd.srpid
UNION
select     srpid,
           null,
           'sum:',
           sum(dollarval) dollarsum
from       productname
group by   srpid 
ORDER BY   4 DESC,
           1 DESC,
           2 DESC
```

Output:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| srpid | weight | dollarval | dollarsum |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     |  1.05  |  155      | 455       |
| 1     |  0.35  |  300      | 455       |
| 1     |        |  sum:     | 455       |
| 3     |  1     |  300      | 440       |
| 3     |  0.01  |  140      | 440       |
| 3     |        |  sum:     | 440       |
| 2     |  0.67  |  170      | 220       |
| 2     |  0.2   |  50       | 220       |
| 2     |        |  sum:     | 220       |
| 5     |  3     |  200      | 200       |
| 5     |        |  sum:     | 200       |
| 4     |  2.04  |  190      | 190       |
| 4     |        |  sum:     | 190       |
+-------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7196c/5).

Comment: trincot, i have more then lacs of records in productname table , and its increase day by day ...so using above inner join ..will not drop my performance ?...btw thanks ..will check your solution ...

Comment: You're welcome. If you are only interested in recent records, e.g. only for the last year, you could put a WHERE condition on a date you maybe store. But performance should not be a problem.